# Why JPA\Hibernate don't automatically create this mapped field?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am working on a Java web application that use JPA\Hibernate and I am not so into this technology.

So I have the following problem: I have a **model** class named **ReaDichiarazioneIntento** that is mapped to a database table named **REA_DICHIARAZIONE_INTENTO**.

Something like this:

```
@javax.persistence.IdClass(it.enel.wearea.entity.ReaDichiarazioneIntentoPK.class)
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "REA_DICHIARAZIONE_INTENTO", schema = "EDIWEA")
@Entity
public class ReaDichiarazioneIntento implements Cloneable {

    private Integer idDichiarazione;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "ID_DICHIARAZIONE")
    @Id
    public Integer getIdDichiarazione() {
        return idDichiarazione;
    }

    public void setIdDichiarazione(Integer idDichiarazione) {
        this.idDichiarazione = idDichiarazione;
    }
    ...................................................................
    ...................................................................
    ...................................................................
    SOME OTHER FIELDS AND RELATED GETTER AND SETTER METHODS
    ...................................................................
    ...................................................................
    ...................................................................

}
```

My boss say to me that I have to add and map a new field into this table, so I have added this field (adding it and the related getter and setter method into the previous class), adding this code to the previous class:

```
private Date dataTrasmissioneAde;

@javax.persistence.Column(name = "DATA_TRASMISSIONE_ADE")
@Basic
public Date getDataTrasmissioneAde() {
    return dataTrasmissioneAde;
}

public void setDataTrasmissioneAde(Date dataTrasmissioneAde) {
    this.dataTrasmissioneAde = dataTrasmissioneAde;
}
```

He say to me that, restarting the application server, Hibernate would automatically create this field into my table.

I obtain no error but looking inside my table I can't find the **DATA_TRASMISSIONE_ADE** column.

Why JPA\Hibernate have not automatically created this column after that I have mapped it into my model class? What could be the problem? What am I missing?

Tnx

Comment: What does the boss say, he obviously knows how it works? :) You should check whether [hbm2ddl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do) is properly configured and triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post your persistence.xml?

it should include something like this

property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"

or drop and create but you will lose all you data if you drop all the tables
You could also put a @Temporal anotation for better mapping to the database of the date field

Comment: this is not a solution for production environments , dev is ok